# Git HEAD~1 behaving not as expected

Tags: version-control, git

Here is my git log:

[image]

I want to reset the most recent commit (top).

If I run `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, however, it takes me back by five commits!

[image]

Similarly, if I run `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, I expect to see the most recent three commits appear, but instead I get about 50!

What could be going wrong?

Comment: If you're going to down vote, please let me know why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual `HEAD` is merge, so it has multiple parents. If you write `HEAD~1`, git must choose from one of the parents. It just chooses the one you do not like.

Use the actual hash instead `HEAD~1` in such situations.

Comment: Ahh. Is there anywhere I can look to learn more about HEAD and merges? I expected HEAD~1 to be one commit behind HEAD.

Comment: But that is what I wrote. How do you define "behind" when the commit has *two* parents (and having two parents is what merge is about)? `HEAD~1` is perfectly fine when `HEAD` has one parent (which is the case of classical commits). To your question - I don't know, try some tutorials or faqs; googling "git HEAD~n merge" may reveal something.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh You can select which parent link to follow with the `^` suffix, `^1` is the default, `^2` is the second parent, etc.  You can also use the `@` suffix to walk through a ref's history rather than a commit's ancestry, e.g. `HEAD@{1}` names the previous `HEAD`, before you last moved it.  The gitrevisions manpage is very helpful.